# Doctrine 2 - relationship OneToOne

Tags: doctrine-orm

It's necessary to add @ORM\JoinColumn in relationship OneToOne in Doctrine 2?

Example:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RaportProductPack", mappedBy="raportProduct")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="raport_product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $raportProductPack;
```

Comment: Hey @sebob! Did you try multiple one to one conditions. What happens when you run doctrine:migrations:diff and then doctrine:migrations:migrate? Is raport_product_id created into table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No, it isn't](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn):

> This annotation is used in the context of relations in @ManyToOne,
>   @OneToOne fields and in the Context of @JoinTable nested inside a
>   @ManyToMany. This annotation is **not required**. If its not specified the
>   attributes name and referencedColumnName are inferred from the table
>   and primary key names.